# convert Qqyyyy to quarter using as.yearqtr

Tags: r, date-formatting, zoo

How do you convert a string like "Q12000" into quarter format using `as.yearqtr` in R?

I have a vector of quarters:

```
x <- c("Q12000", "Q22000", "Q32000")
```

I tried the following code:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearqtr(x, format = "Q%q%Y")
# [1] NA NA NA
```

The result should be "2000 Q1" "2000 Q2" "2000 Q3". Instead, I get all `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the implementation does not understand that a quarter can be only one digit so it needs to be delimited by a non-digit. For example, insert a space after the quarter:

```
as.yearqtr(sub("(..)", "\\1 ", x), format = "Q%q %Y")
## [1] "2000 Q1" "2000 Q2" "2000 Q3"
```

or put it into default format first:

```
as.yearqtr(sub("Q(.)(....)", "\\2-\\1", x))
## [1] "2000 Q1" "2000 Q2" "2000 Q3"
```

**Note:**

```
x <- c("Q12000", "Q22000", "Q32000")
```